# What is the best way to implement a continuous promise based process in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, eventemitter

I'm working on a project in which I need to create a continuous Node process that repeatedly carries out some promise based tasks over and over again without an end time. The first promise cycle has to be complete before the next begins. I'm puzzling over what is the best way to implement this, and whether there are pros and cons to different approaches.

The two solutions I am considering so far are:

**A recursive function:**

```
var repeat = function () {
    MethodThatReturnsAPromise()
        .then(function () {
            repeat();
        });
};

repeat();
```

**Using the node eventemitter**

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var run = function () {
    MethodThatReturnsAPromise()
        .then(function () {
            eventEmitter.emit('complete');
        });
};

eventEmitter.on('complete', function () {
    run();
});

run();
```

At the moment I'm leaning towards the event based approach.

Is there any reason why either approach is more 'correct' or idiomatic to node, or does it just not really matter (and I'm just obsessing over details)? Or is there a third, better way of implementing this, that I am not aware of (I'm quite new to node)?

Comment: Your first implementation is likely the best way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is it about that approach that you think is better?

Comment: Because promises are a high level, cleaner abstraction over event emitter. No reason to use event emitter unless you absolutely have to, and in this case, I don't see why you would.

Comment: Interesting. I moved away from the first solution initially, because when running it in conjuction with node-inspector (so I could find a memory leak in my promise code), I found I could not use the 'record heap allocations' feature, presumably because the recursive function never completes so inspector couldn't do an object count. This made me suspect it was an iffy solution to have a function that never completes. This problem doesn't happen with the eventemitter code. Do you not reckon that justifies using the event approach?

Comment: It's not strictly a function that never completes, if it was synchronous then it would ultimately blow the stack at some point, but it's asynchronous, meaning it doesn't actually use a stack. It's more of a loop that never completes, but written as a recursive function. At the end of the day, it's doing exactly the same thing as your event emitter implementation.